# Expected a type, but ‘Request’ has kind ‘* -> *’

Tags: haskell

I wrote simple hello world server (http) and i have declared my request handler's type as,

```
type RequestHandler = Request -> IO Response
```

It throws error as,

```
simpleserver.hs:11:23:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Request’
    Expected a type, but ‘Request’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    In the type ‘Request -> IO Response’
    In the type declaration for ‘RequestHandler’
```

[complete-code](https://github.com/madhavan020985/haskell-examples/blob/master/simpleserver.hs#L11)

This error message makes no sense to me..

Why is this error thrown and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Request`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.20/docs/Network-HTTP-Base.html#t:Request) has data in the form of a generic type attached to it (the `a` in `Request a` and it represents the request-*body*) - this is meant when Haskell tells you that `Request` has **kind** `* -> *`

So you basically have to fix it - either think of a fixed type and add it:

```
type RequestHandler = Request String -> IO Response
```

there are already types for this (for example [`Request_String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.20/docs/Network-HTTP-Base.html#t:Request_String) so you could say:

```
type RequestHandler = Request_String -> IO Response
```

too. Or you make your handler generic:

```
type RequestHandler a = Request a -> IO Response
```

of course with this you will have to change some of your other functions/definitions too (for example the `helloWorldHandler`).

Answer (score 2):

[Look at](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.20/docs/Network-HTTP-Base.html#t:Request) the type of `Request`: it needs a single type parameter, which it uses to determine what to do with the body of the http request. That's exactly what the error message is telling you: haskell expected one argument to `Request`, and you gave it zero.